# How to display handlebars templates on two separate pages?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have 2 HTML pages (page1.html and page2.html) and 1 data source. I'm able to display the handlebars data in page1.html by essentially making the entire page into a template

page1.html:

```
<body>
    <div class="row" id="content-placeholder"></div>
      <script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <h1>{{Title}}</h1>
      </script>
```

data.js

```
var source   = $("#some-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var gData = {
   title: 'My Website'//,...
}


$("#content-placeholder").html(template(gData));
```

This works, but I'd like to display part of the same data object on the second html page.

page2.html

```
<body>
<div class="row" id="content-placeholder2"></div>
  <script id="second-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  </script>
```

I tried using partials but I don't think that's the solution. How can I compile two templates?

Thanks!